# Rundeck - dynamic mapping for ssh keys

Tags: rundeck

I am looking into importing my nodes using the EC2 plugin
My mapping is setup to import the key as one of the values, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to concatenate the dynamic value coming from the node with the string that will represent the ssh key path. Effectively what I would like to achieve is something along those lines:

ssh-keypath.default=/path/to/key/directory/${keyName}.pem;

this, however sets my keypath to literal "/path/to/key/directory/${keyName}.pem"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

1. In **Mapping Params** i set *keyName.selector=keyName;*
2. In Default Node Executor / SSH Key File path i can now set */path/to/keys/${node.keyName}.pem*

This means that if I add all of my keys to /path/to/keys/ they will load dynamically as long as the keyName is correct.

Comment: Thanks posting this, I have been looking into this today too.